# Qt How to pass data from a GUI to another thread

Tags: c++, qt

I have an application that can start pause and cancel the thread.
i would like to pass data from the main gui to the thread. 
in this example i have a spinbox. 
i wish to reset the counter in the worker thread everytime i change the spin box.

for some reason i can't seem to update the counter variable in the worker thread. 
what am i missing in my program?

MAINWINDOW.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
    #define MAINWINDOW_H

    #include <QMainWindow>
    #include <QThread>

    #include "worker.h"

    namespace Ui {
    class MainWindow;
    }

    class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    signals:
        void updatecounter(int val);

    public:
        explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
        ~MainWindow();

    private slots:


        void on_Time_valueChanged(const QString &arg1);

        void on_Start_clicked();

        void on_Stop_clicked();

        void on_Pause_clicked();

    private:
        Ui::MainWindow *ui;
        QThread        *m_Thread;
        Worker         *m_Worker;

    };

    #endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

WORKER.h

```
#ifndef WORKER_H
#define WORKER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QMutex>
#include <QThread>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QEventLoop>
#include <QAbstractEventDispatcher>

class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Worker();
    ~Worker();

public slots:
    void process();

signals:
    void started();
    void finished();

   public slots:

       void updatecounter(int val)
       {
           counter = val;
       }

       void pause()
       {
           auto const dispatcher = QThread::currentThread()->eventDispatcher();

           if (!dispatcher)
           {
               qCritical() << "thread with no dispatcher";
               return;
           }

           if (state != RUNNING)
               return;

           state = PAUSED;
           qDebug() << this;
           qDebug() << "paused";

           do
           {
               dispatcher->processEvents(QEventLoop::WaitForMoreEvents);
           } while (state == PAUSED);
       }

       void resume()
       {
           if (state == PAUSED)
           {
               state = RUNNING;
               qDebug() << this;
               qDebug() << "resumed";

               updatecounter(0);
           }
       }

       void cancel()
       {
           if (state != IDLE)
           {
               state = IDLE;
               qDebug() << this;
               qDebug() << "cancelled";
           }
       }

   protected:

       enum State { IDLE, RUNNING, PAUSED };
       State state = IDLE;
       int counter = 0;
       bool isCancelled()
       {
           auto const dispatcher = QThread::currentThread()->eventDispatcher();

           if (!dispatcher)
           {
               qCritical() << "thread with no dispatcher";
               return false;
           }

           dispatcher->processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents);

           return state == IDLE;
       }
};

#endif // WORKER_H
```

MAINWINDOW.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    qDebug() << "main thread";

    m_Thread = new QThread();

    ui->Start->setEnabled(true);
    ui->Pause->setEnabled(false);
    ui->Stop->setEnabled(false);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_Time_valueChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
    emit updatecounter(arg1.toInt());


    //auto const m = m_Worker->metaObject();
    //m->invokeMethod(m_Worker, "updatecounter",Qt::QueuedConnection,Q_ARG(int,arg1.toInt()));
}

void MainWindow::on_Start_clicked()
{
    if(!m_Thread->isRunning())
    {
        m_Thread = new QThread();
        m_Worker = new Worker();
        m_Worker->moveToThread(m_Thread);

        connect(m_Thread, &QThread::started, m_Worker, &Worker::process);
        connect(this,&MainWindow::updatecounter, m_Worker, &Worker::updatecounter, Qt::QueuedConnection);
        connect(m_Worker, &Worker::finished, m_Thread, &QThread::quit);
        m_Thread->start();

    }
    else
    {
        auto const m = m_Worker->metaObject();
        m->invokeMethod(m_Worker, "resume");
    }

    ui->Start->setEnabled(false);
    ui->Pause->setEnabled(true);
    ui->Stop->setEnabled(true);
}

void MainWindow::on_Stop_clicked()
{
    auto const m = m_Worker->metaObject();
    m->invokeMethod(m_Worker, "cancel");
    ui->Start->setEnabled(true);
    ui->Pause->setEnabled(false);
    ui->Stop->setEnabled(false);

}

void MainWindow::on_Pause_clicked()
{
    auto const m = m_Worker->metaObject();
    m->invokeMethod(m_Worker, "pause");
    ui->Start->setEnabled(true);
    ui->Pause->setEnabled(false);
    ui->Stop->setEnabled(true);
}
```

WORKER.cpp

```
#include "worker.h"

#include <QDebug>
#include <QThread>
#include <QTimer>

Worker::Worker()
{
    qDebug() << this << " worker thread started";
}

Worker::~Worker()
{
    qDebug() << "worker thread finished";
}

void Worker::process()
{
    if (state == PAUSED)
               // treat as resume
               state = RUNNING;

           if (state == RUNNING)
               return;

           state = RUNNING;
           qDebug() << "started";
           emit started();

           // This loop simulates the actual work
           for (auto i = counter;  state == RUNNING;  ++i)
           {
               QThread::msleep(100);
               if (isCancelled())
               {
                   break;
               }

               qDebug() << i;
           }

           qDebug() << this;
           qDebug() << "finished";
           emit finished();
}
```

Comment: In `Qt` you may want to use signals and slots for this if the data you want to transfer is not GBs.

Comment: I am emitting a signal. emit updatecounter(arg1.toInt()); the worker thread receives it except it doesn't reset the loop. in the process method.

Comment: connect(this,&MainWindow::updatecounter, m_Worker, &Worker::updatecounter, Qt::QueuedConnection);

Comment: If your thread is executing the loop in `Worker::process()` your slot will not be called. It will only be called when the thread is not executing any other function.

Comment: How then can i update the variables inside process?

Comment: I think you want to divide up process to multiple slots. This is a difference between event based programming and procedural programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is:

```
// This loop simulates the actual work
for (auto i = counter;  state == RUNNING;  ++i)
{
    QThread::msleep(100);
    if (isCancelled())
    {
         break;
    }

    qDebug() << i;
}
```

This is effectively an infinite loop. The problem is while your thread is stuck in this loop it never returns to the `Qthread::exec` (your main event loop) which is what processes all the signals and slots on the thread.

In Qt you should always return back to your event loop as quickly as possible. Sleeps are a big no-no. For periodic work use a `QTimer`.

Comment: I created a timer on the mainwindow and used that to call functions in the worker thread, application seems to work as intended now, but is this the correct way?

Comment: You probably should have created a timer on your worker thread. Calling functions from the mainwindow would happen in the mainwindow's thread.